# Google FIT Api history data retrieved does not merge steps by default

Tags: android, google-fit

So to retrieve step count, I use following code piece:

```
fun getFitnessData(startTime: Long, endTime: Long): DataReadRequest {
    return DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .bucketByTime(..., TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
}
```

this works very good when recorded steps were done using a phone, but whenever user has a watch as well, then step count is returned incorrectly.

For instance, if user phone records 30 steps, then watch also record 30 steps and returned result is 60 steps, but I'd expect that phone/watch returns 30 steps in th

Answer (score 0):

The merging of data seems expected behavior. Per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq), the step counts from watch and phone are merged to get the most complete step count. When merging data, watch data is prioritised over phone data (prioritisation avoids counting duplicate steps). The Google Fit platform returns this accurate, merged information when you read the data type.